# Xcode Rename Variables Across Multiple Files

Tags: xcode, variables, rename

Normally in Xcode, when you hover over a variable name, Xcode will underline it and place a triangle to the right of the variable name that you can click on and select "edit all in scope."  This allows you to rename all instances of a variable at once.  However, this doesn't seem to work if you are working across multiple files, for example, when writing a program that has a header file with the class specifications, the cpp with the implementation, and maybe a main that tests the class.  This method of changing all variable names doesn't work in this situation, that I know of.  It allows you to change all variable names of one page, but it doesn't change the same variable elsewhere.  Is there a way around this?  I tried the refactoring menu, but I guess refactoring isn't supported in non-Apple languages, like C++.  I hoping that there is a better option for multi-page variable renaming, other than using search and replace.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, refactoring isn't even supported in all Apple languages...Swift, for example.  (I use an Objective-C++ code-base at work and sympathize with your problem.)

Comment: Why not just use the `Find` feature and search / replace your variable there.

Comment: I really enjoy using Xcode, but the lack of refactoring is quite bothersome.  I'm not sure why Apple allows us to rename all instances of a variable within one file, but not across multiple files.  If I write my classes all in one file, I have no issue renaming variables and functions, but splitting them into .h and .cpp makes renaming a pain.